# Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property: productline of:

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to write the JPQL of below query. I am using *Spring Boot v.2.2.2.RELEASE and Spring Data JPA*.

Error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: productline of: com.example.entity.Productline [SELECT p FROM com.example.entity.Product p JOIN p.productline pl WHERE p.productline = pl.productline]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:600) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:709) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: productline of: com.example.entity.Productline
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2015) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:407) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:516) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:1045) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1290) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4706) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4177) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2138) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:815) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:609) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

Select Query

```
SELECT 
    productCode, 
    productName, 
    textDescription
FROM
    products t1
INNER JOIN productlines t2 
    ON t1.productline = t2.productline;
```

Repository

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String>{

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Product p INNER JOIN p.productline pl ON p.productline=pl.productline")
    List<Product> findProductsAndProductLines(); 
}
```

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
@NamedQuery(name="Product.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Product p")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, length=15)
    private String productCode;

    @Column(nullable=false, precision=10, scale=2)
    private BigDecimal buyPrice;

    @Column(nullable=false, precision=10, scale=2)
    private BigDecimal msrp;

    @Lob
    @Type(type = "text")
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String productDescription;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=70)
    private String productName;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=10)
    private String productScale;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=50)
    private String productVendor;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private short quantityInStock;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Orderdetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
    private List<Orderdetail> orderdetails;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Productline
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="productLine", nullable=false)
    private Productline productline;

    public Product() {
    }

    public String getProductCode() {
        return this.productCode;
    }

    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBuyPrice() {
        return this.buyPrice;
    }

    public void setBuyPrice(BigDecimal buyPrice) {
        this.buyPrice = buyPrice;
    }

    public BigDecimal getMsrp() {
        return this.msrp;
    }

    public void setMsrp(BigDecimal msrp) {
        this.msrp = msrp;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return this.productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return this.productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductScale() {
        return this.productScale;
    }

    public void setProductScale(String productScale) {
        this.productScale = productScale;
    }

    public String getProductVendor() {
        return this.productVendor;
    }

    public void setProductVendor(String productVendor) {
        this.productVendor = productVendor;
    }

    public short getQuantityInStock() {
        return this.quantityInStock;
    }

    public void setQuantityInStock(short quantityInStock) {
        this.quantityInStock = quantityInStock;
    }

    public List<Orderdetail> getOrderdetails() {
        return this.orderdetails;
    }

    public void setOrderdetails(List<Orderdetail> orderdetails) {
        this.orderdetails = orderdetails;
    }

    public Orderdetail addOrderdetail(Orderdetail orderdetail) {
        getOrderdetails().add(orderdetail);
        orderdetail.setProduct(this);

        return orderdetail;
    }

    public Orderdetail removeOrderdetail(Orderdetail orderdetail) {
        getOrderdetails().remove(orderdetail);
        orderdetail.setProduct(null);

        return orderdetail;
    }

    public Productline getProductline() {
        return this.productline;
    }

    public void setProductline(Productline productline) {
        this.productline = productline;
    }
}
```

**Productline.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="productlines")
@NamedQuery(name="Productline.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Productline p")
public class Productline implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, length=50)
    private String productLine;

    @Lob
    @Type(type = "text")
    private String htmlDescription;

    // Ref: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch03.html
    @Lob
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.ImageType")
    private byte[] image;

    @Column(length=4000)
    private String textDescription;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Product
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="productline")
    private List<Product> products;

    public Productline() {
    }

    public String getProductLine() {
        return this.productLine;
    }

    public void setProductLine(String productLine) {
        this.productLine = productLine;
    }

    public String getHtmlDescription() {
        return this.htmlDescription;
    }

    public void setHtmlDescription(String htmlDescription) {
        this.htmlDescription = htmlDescription;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTextDescription() {
        return this.textDescription;
    }

    public void setTextDescription(String textDescription) {
        this.textDescription = textDescription;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public Product addProduct(Product product) {
        getProducts().add(product);
        product.setProductline(this);

        return product;
    }

    public Product removeProduct(Product product) {
        getProducts().remove(product);
        product.setProductline(null);

        return product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try with p.productLine only for Product entity reference as  you have defined @JoinColumn(name="productLine")

Comment: @MyTwoCents - Sorry I did not follow you. Can you pls explain more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because of this line `p.productline=pl.productline`

`Productline` entity doesn't have productline.

With `p.productline` all the mapping will be taking care. Also INNER is optional.

Your final query should be like this

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p JOIN p.productline pl")
List<Product> findProductsAndProductLines();
```

Refer [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_inner_joins) for more Detail

Comment: above JPQL and SELECT 
    productCode, 
    productName, 
    textDescription
FROM
    products t1
INNER JOIN productlines t2 
    ON t1.productline = t2.productline; both are eqivalent ?

Comment: when you add p.productline in the query, hibernate will map it as an inner join query. So yes they are the same. You can try running and check for query in console. if query print in enable

Comment: Great ! Thanks for the confirmation. Can you please provide doc links for such informations? I am trying for Left Outer Join in JPQL hope this will work

Comment: I just ran: `@Query("SELECT c.customerNumber, c.customerName, o.orderNumber,o.status FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN c.orders o")` and console shows `elect
        customer0_.customerNumber as col_0_0_,
        customer0_.customerName as col_1_0_,
        orders1_.orderNumber as col_2_0_,
        orders1_.status as col_3_0_ 
    from
        customers customer0_ 
    left outer join
        orders orders1_ 
            on customer0_.customerNumber=orders1_.customerNumber`, so its very perfect

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_inner_joins

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with the provided code snippet.

1. You should pass a *JPQL* query to your `@Query` annotation by default. Which means that **you should not write manual JOIN operators.** E.g. `SELECT p FROM Product p join p.productline` will result in a proper SQL. However, you **should not do that.**
2. `JpaRepository` provides all common methods. So you can use `findAll()`, and fetch all products. **A `productLine` will be loaded automatically for each product in that case.** That's because a default fetch type for `toOne` relations is `EAGER`. This means that every time you load an entity, a *JPA* provider (in this case *Hibernate*) will load its `toOne` relations.
3. If you want to force *Spring Data* to generate an `INNER JOIN` you should tell it that **this relation is not optional**. You can do that by putting `@ManyToOne(optional=false)` on you `productLine`.

**The answer to your question:** that error is caused by syntax error, `ON p.productline=pl.productline`. As you can see, **`pl` does not have a `productLine` field.** In order to get the desired SQL query with `INNER JOIN`, please follow 3 recommendations above.